# Validate uniqueness of column with locale and case sensitive in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, internationalization

I would like to validate the uniqueness of my model name without being case sensitive. I tried many ways but doesn't seem to work when it's a hash with internationalization

For example, for name column => `{"en"=>"Boston", "fr"=>"Boston"}` I don't want to accept `"boston"` as correct.

Here's my current attempt at validating my locales:

```
I18n.available_locales.each do |locale|
 validates :description, translation_uniqueness: { locale: locale }
 validates :name, translation_uniqueness: { locale: locale, case_sensitive: false }
end
```

But `case_sensitive` doesn't work. How can I use `case_sensitive` with locales?

Comment: Where is `translation_uniqueness` defined? I don't think it's part of Rails.

Comment: Yes its custom i tried

Comment: Not sure I understand is there a reason you cannot just use `validates :name, uniqueness: { scope: :locale, case_sensitive: false }`? Also is there a reason that a description cannot be the same for a different name?

Comment: Sounds like you want it to be case sensitive? You said you want `Boston != boston` this is `case-sensitive: true` which is the default behaviour.